# Password reset email is not valid?

Tags: 7, users

In setting up a new Drupal 7 site, I went to try out the password reset option, and while I received the password reset email just fine, clicking it takes me to a page with an error "You have tried to use a one-time login link that has either been used or is no longer valid".

I've tried sending the reset email a few times and clicking the link immediately each time, and keep getting the same error message. What sort of things make a reset link "no longer valid"? I'm working on a staging server that will be translated to a live server, so URLs and cookie paths might be getting tangled; where do I need to start looking to unravel this?

Note: The user accounts being tested were imported using the Migrate module from another system, hence their passwords are invalid, and I'm hoping users can just request a new password to login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not documented nicely anywhere I can find, but it seems that you can't use the password reset option via email for a user who's an Administrator of the site. Instead you have to use some alternate method to change the database directly, like [this](http://randyfay.com/comment/1990).

Answer (score -1):

That's not the case - you should be able to get admin password reset by using the link /user/password . The problem I found was its not set to my domain, instead it set to gmail.com .

After i changed to my domain, I started getting emails for Password Reset from my D7 installation.

Comment: The issue for me wasn't that I wasn't receiving the emails (you say you "started getting emails" when you solved it), but rather that the links themselves gave a Drupal error when visited.